# Is there any reason not to install PHP as 64bit on a Windows 2008 R2 server?

Tags: php, 64-bit, windows-server-2008-r2

Do all the modules and libraries (third party and non-third party) work in 64bit?  I read other questions on SO, but I have not seen anything recent.  I wanted to install 5.5.1 64bit.  Is 64bit flaky?

Also was hoping to find out if there is any advantage to 64 over 32 other than the size of an integer or other number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

64-bit PHP is no more flakey than 32-bit PHP on Windows or any other platform.... but there's fewer of the modules and extensions you might need available as 64-bit Windows dlls, despite Pierre Joye's best efforts

**Benefits of 64-bit**

- Larger range of values for numeric data types
- Can handle larger files
  (file pointer is 64-bit as well)

**Drawbacks**

- Heavier memory consumption (my own estimates are about 60% additional overhead for a typical application)

Comment: Why would I want that big overhead?  What do you mean larger files, btw.  What file could 32bit not handle?  Thanks.

Comment: The file pointer in 32-bit PHP is a 32-bit signed integer, so the maximum filesize it can handle is 2,147,483,647 bytes (2GB); in 64-bit PHP, the file pointer is a 64-bit signed integer, allowing you to work with filesizes up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 bytes (9eB, if you had files that large, and enough disk space)

Comment: Why might you want that memory overhead? If you weren't worried about memory, but did need to work with integers outside the normal −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 range without resorting to the much slower bcmath or gmp extensions (ie. speed matters more than memory usage)